# How to match this kind of string in Python use re?

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I have several strings like these:

```
unicode 0, <runtime error >,0
unicode 0, <TLOSS error>
unicode 0, <- Attempt to use MSIL code >
unicode 0, <ModuleNameA>
```

I am trying to use re to match all the string inside "<" ">"

I tried this :

```
items = line.split()
pattern = r"<.+?>"
match = re.findall(pattern, items[2])
```

But it seems that space can not be deal with..

Could anyone give me some help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`items[2]` contains partial content:

```
>>> items = line.split()
>>> items[2]
'<runtime'
```

Just pass the `line` to the `re.findall`:

```
>>> line = 'unicode 0, <runtime error >,0'
>>> re.findall(r'<.+?>', line)
['<runtime error >']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't split them and use the string as it is, like this

```
line = "unicode 0, <runtime error >,0"
import re
print(re.findall(r"<.+?>", line))
# ['<runtime error >']
```

If you want only the string inside that, you can do

```
print(re.search(r"<(.+?)>", line).group(1))
# runtime error
```